# How can I send to the server a file and string in C#?

Tags: c#, python, httpclient

I'm uploading an image to the server, but I want to upload it together with a string. I have this code that has been working good for me. I don't know exactly where I have to put a line of code that allows me to do that.

```
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(pathOfTheImage);
        string fileName = fi.Name;
        byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);

        Uri webService = new Uri(@"http://" + ipAddress+ ":" + port.ToString()+ "/cnn");
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, webService);
        requestMessage.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;

        MultipartFormDataContent multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("----MyGreatBoundary");
        ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileContents);
        byteArrayContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        multiPartContent.Add(byteArrayContent, "img", fileName);
        requestMessage.Content = multiPartContent;

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> httpRequest = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage,
                                                                     HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead,
                                                                     CancellationToken.None);
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = httpRequest.Result;
        outputOfTheCNN = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        requestMessage.Dispose();
        multiPartContent.Dispose();
        byteArrayContent.Dispose();
        httpRequest.Dispose();
        httpResponse.Dispose();
        httpClient.Dispose();
```

The client is written in Python

On the client, I have like this:
file = request.files['img']

I only need to have somethimg like the same but:
device = request.files['device']

Comment: Don't you just need to add another item to the `mutliPartContent` object?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. That's why I'm asking. If you can help, it'd be awesome! :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on it myself, tbh, but that's what stood out to me as what's likely to be "the place to do it".

Comment: Yes, you were right. I only had to add it and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Please can you add your solution as an answer to your question. :-)

Comment: Sure!
 multiPartContent.Add(byteArrayContent, "img", fileName);
C-Sharp: multiPartContent.Add(devices,"devices");    <----- I only added this line.
Python: kind_of_device = request.form['devices']        <----Client Side.

Comment: Oh, as an answer (box below) :) So I can upvote it.